# popToViewController with interactivePopGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using the following code

```
[self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(handlePopGesture:)];

- (void)handlePopGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{

 } else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    NSArray *views = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[views objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
}
```

but its not working any ideas how to pop view controller using interactivePopGestureRecognizer?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your .h file is the delegate.

```
@interface YOURVIEWCONTROLLER : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

In your .m include

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Then your delegate method should recognize your gestures.

Comment: Careful when trying to swipe pop the root controller http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698018/interactivepopgesturerecognizer-corrupts-navigation-stack-on-root-view-controlle